# Starting a new Drupal 7 multilingual site

Tags: drupal-7, multilingual

I am starting my first multilingual Drupal site and I have doubts between using entity translation or just using i18n for the content translation.

Some important notes that have to be taken into account:

- Site must be SEO-friendly, that means that every content will have a different URL (not the same URL for every language). Apparently this can be covered with both of them.
- Site will have no comments, so there will be no language mix comments from entity translation.
- Site will be translated to 3 languages.

I am pretty convinced that entity translation is the way to go, but as it is my first multilingual from scratch I would like to hear some opinions from people who have already fought this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need both modules. **Entity translation** + **Title** for content and **i18n** for other stuff like blocks and field names.

If your content will mirror each other in different languages, then check  **Enabled, with field translation** under your content type settings so you don't get three nodes for the same thing in three languages. There will be only one node but some fields, which are language dependent, will be translated.

I'm using this settings for the last two years with Drupal7 multilang websites and it goes quite smooth.